# Mechanism for the Beilstein test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, analytical-chemistry

What is a possible mechanism for the Beilstein test for halogens ? I can't seem to find a arrow pushing mechanism for this reaction.

Comment: You can easily find it if you dig google enough. I do know the answer, but not going to write one and recommend to search it yourself, it is easy.

Comment: Please, I tried a Google search but I could not find one. If writing the mechanism is too much work, please give me a link. Thank You !

Comment: I was under the impression that the goal of a stack exchange was so that, when you googled a question, the top result would be a stack exchange result. This was the stated goal on Stack Overflow; I'm not sure if it's extended to all sites on the stack exchange network

Comment: hmm..well its listed as the fourth result. Maybe if someone helped me figure out the mechanism, it might become the first result...

Comment: @permeakra Please share your wisdom. I tried finding it on google (for a good while) and managed nothing. And frankly, I find your attitude a little disturbing.

Comment: @permeakra I agree with Martin; I would like to add that you usually have useful contributions, and I would like to hear them even if answers are readily found online. It's always great getting a second opinion.

Comment: @PeprikaDesilva Actually, wiki article includes pretty correct description, wich is duplicated now in the answer. Beilstein test is a variation of flame test. In flame test many elements form particles with strong emission lines in spectrum, coloring the flame. Copper is somewhat pathological case as it may form several different species, giving different colors: monochloride (700-1000 C, Cl present. blue), atomic species (green), and oxide (oxidative atmosphere, golden). In reductive atmosphere of the reasonably hot flame organics breaks and copper monochloride is formed. Learn google-fu.

Comment: @Martin With all respect, google-fu is something I strongly recommend to learn. Yes, there IS much to learn using google: what words to use, how to generalize them, secondary searches (search for topics found on pages after first request), advanced search features. But in modern days it is something one really need to know.

Comment: @permeakra With all respect, sir, I very much encourage you to share your knowledge. Maybe a link to a tutorial on how to intelligent use the search engines would be not only very helpful, but also very much appreciated. I might have missed some important information and I wish to not continue living without it. Maybe I am just plain stupid, according to your tone, you must think that. (One could guess, that I am outraged, and I really have to behave myself to not use strong language here.)

Comment: @permeakra The given answer as well as your previous comment ***cannot*** be seen as an actual [mechanism](http://goldbook.iupac.org/M03804.html). Those are net reaction equations, with no information about the process, that can be referred to as a reaction path, whatsoever. And if you had read the question carefully, you would have noticed, that the mechanism was looked for.

Comment: @Martin Google has advanced search http://www.google.com/advanced_search . Two most useful options has shortcuts usable directly from the main page: "-word", to find pages without the word and "site:url", performing search on the site with specific prefix. When searching for scientific information, scholar.google.com is also very handful. Other than that it is mostly the matter of practices, I guess.

Comment: @Martin What do you want? Specific details how organic chlorides breaks?

Comment: I spent about a half hour looking this up yesterday, even going as far as to read several papers in JACS. Nowhere did I find an arrow-pushing mechanism (though I did find a fun one that claimed that CO2 can be generated from nothing). Yes, the info in prooffreader's answer can be found widely, but it doesn't explain how the chlorine is stripped from the organic, or what happens to the organic afterward (I can make several really, really good guesses, but that doesn't make the answer obvious)

Comment: @chipbuster ... and I readily got http://prr.hec.gov.pk/Thesis/3645H.pdf from 'thermal dehydrohalogenation' from google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you heat the copper wire in a flame, it is oxidized on the surface to copper (II) oxide:

$$\ce{2Cu(s) + O2(g) -> 2CuO(s)}$$

Then when you mix it with the halide and heat it, the higher reduction potential makes it displace the oxygen.

Here's an example with sodium chloride:

$$\ce{CuO(s) + 2NaCl(s) -> CuCl2(g) + Na2O}$$

Copper halides are volatile (except for fluorides); the gas is hot enough to push some electrons into an excited state, and as they cool a tiny bit, the electrons drop back into their rest state and emit the excess energy in the form of a photon with a wavelength corresponding to the color green.

Comment: Chlorine, however, is less electronegative than oxygen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I meant reduction potential. I'm not my best at one in the morning!

Comment: I heard that even before mixing the halide, when you are heating the copper wire, a green colour flame might be seen. So you must wait till that colour disappears before you mix the halide. This is probably due to impurities of halides in the environment or on the wire. So what do these halides convert into - considering the green colour disappears after some time?